# Get text after each nth occurrence from string and number them

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

Querying Redshift through Aginity

I have a small table with just 1 field in and I want to get the value after each occurrence of the `XX` value up to the next space and also a column to number each occurrence.

**MYTABLE:**

```
MYFIELD
The quick XX brown fox XX jumps over the XX lazy dog
Get text XX after each XX nth XX occurrence XX from string
```

**Desired Output:**

```
MYFIELD                                                     OCC   FIELDOUTPUT
The quick XX brown fox XX jumps over the XX lazy dog        1     brown  
The quick XX brown fox XX jumps over the XX lazy dog        2     jumps
The quick XX brown fox XX jumps over the XX lazy dog        3     lazy
Get text XX after each XX nth XX occurrence XX from string  1     after
Get text XX after each XX nth XX occurrence XX from string  2     nth
Get text XX after each XX nth XX occurrence XX from string  3     occurrence 
Get text XX after each XX nth XX occurrence XX from string  4    from
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/991c8d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH dummy_values AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
)
, seq AS (
  SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())::INT occ 
  FROM dummy_values d1, dummy_values d2, dummy_values d3
)
SELECT 
  "MYFIELD"
, occ
, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR("MYFIELD", 'XX \\S+', 1, occ), 'XX ', '') fieldoutput
FROM mytable
JOIN seq ON occ <= REGEXP_COUNT("MYFIELD", 'XX ')
```

Comment: @Matt, this answer is valid for postgresql, i see the question has been edited and now refers to redshift, please see the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You could split string with `ORDINALITY`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM MyTABLE, regexp_split_to_table(MYFIELD, E'\\s+') WITH ORDINALITY s(c,rn)
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT myfield, c, LEAD(c) OVER(PARTITION BY MYFIELD ORDER BY rn) AS FieldOutput, rn 
  FROM cte
)
SELECT MYFIELD, Fieldoutput,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MYFIELD ORDER BY rn) AS occ
FROM cte2
WHERE c = 'XX'
ORDER BY MYFIELD,rn;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=294272d252318011ebf5c1d1c8de6352)**

Comment: Getting an error: `ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "WITH"`

Comment: @Matt Please try version with inline views: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c566da2f9cb8526f0b37acdca5607a76